# xtext: Statements in different order

Tags: xtext

I'm trying to write a xtext rule, where I can write statements in different random orders but all statements have to be saved as a list.

I tried:

```
Root:
 ( (entity += Entity)? & (component += Component)? )*
;
```

But it doesn’t work. 
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to achieve for goals:

- Use Svens answer for the grammar part. This allows you to mix Entities and Components freely.
- Add a custom validation check to ensure that at least one Entity and at least one Component is there.

The docu for custom validations is in the chapter [Validation](https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/303_runtime_concepts.html#validation), subchapter "Custom Validation".

Answer (score 2):

This does what you've asked for:

```
Root:
  (entity+=Entity | component+=Component)*
;
```

Comment: This is what I have been looking for.
But how I can change this rule into a rule where Entity and Component have to appear at least once.

Answer (score 1):

Just to supplement the answer, and to answer toms question in the comments. To do what is asked for while ensuring both Entity and Component appear at least once I still think it would be best to follow [Sven Efftinges answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16184020/10171898), and afterward implement a validator to ensure both an Entity and Component appears at least once.
Generally, it is best to keep the grammar syntax simple and do more advanced checks with validators.